# Scrape webpage that requires button click

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, netstat

I am trying to scrape data from the link below. I need to click and download a `csv` file available in the `csv` button from the webpage.

```
library(netstat)
library(RSelenium)

url <- https://gtr.ukri.org/search/project?term=%22climate+change%22+OR+%22climate+crisis%22&fetchSize=25&selectedSortableField=&selectedSortOrder=&fields=pro.gr%2Cpro.t%2Cpro.a%2Cpro.orcidId%2Cper.fn%2Cper.on%2Cper.sn%2Cper.fnsn%2Cper.orcidId%2Cper.org.n%2Cper.pro.t%2Cper.pro.abs%2Cpub.t%2Cpub.a%2Cpub.orcidId%2Corg.n%2Corg.orcidId%2Cacp.t%2Cacp.d%2Cacp.i%2Cacp.oid%2Ckf.d%2Ckf.oid%2Cis.t%2Cis.d%2Cis.oid%2Ccol.i%2Ccol.d%2Ccol.c%2Ccol.dept%2Ccol.org%2Ccol.pc%2Ccol.pic%2Ccol.oid%2Cip.t%2Cip.d%2Cip.i%2Cip.oid%2Cpol.i%2Cpol.gt%2Cpol.in%2Cpol.oid%2Cprod.t%2Cprod.d%2Cprod.i%2Cprod.oid%2Crtp.t%2Crtp.d%2Crtp.i%2Crtp.oid%2Crdm.t%2Crdm.d%2Crdm.i%2Crdm.oid%2Cstp.t%2Cstp.d%2Cstp.i%2Cstp.oid%2Cso.t%2Cso.d%2Cso.cn%2Cso.i%2Cso.oid%2Cff.t%2Cff.d%2Cff.c%2Cff.org%2Cff.dept%2Cff.oid%2Cdis.t%2Cdis.d%2Cdis.i%2Cdis.oid%2Ccpro.rtpc%2Ccpro.rcpgm%2Ccpro.hlt&type=#/csvConfirm
```

I am struggling to implement that using `Selenium`. Here is the code I have so far.

```
rD <- rsDriver(port= free_port(), browser = "chrome", chromever = "106.0.5249.21", check = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
remote_driver <- rD[["client"]] 
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(url)

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "content gtr-body d-flex flex-column ng-scope")
webElem$clickElement()
```

Comment: I don't think Selenium is the best option here. I can probably send you something eaiser if you provide some additional info. What is it that you want to collect from the website?

Comment: If you open the url I shared, there is a button named `csv` that I need to click and download the file

Answer (score 0):

You can often just record the network log and see what request is sent when hitting the download button. In Chrome, right click Inspect, then look for the network tab. In this case there is only one request sent:

[image]

Right click and "copy as cURL" to see the whole request or just click copy URL, since the cookies and headers are not necessary here. I wrote a quick function around the task of querying the site:

```r
dl_ukri <- function(query,
                    destfile = paste0(query, ".csv"),
                    size = 25L,
                    quiet_download = FALSE) {
  
  url <- paste0(
    "https://gtr.ukri.org/search/project/csv?term=",
    urltools::url_encode(query),
    "&selectedFacets=&fields=acp.d,is.t,prod.t,pol.oid,acp.oid,rtp.t,pol.in,prod.i,per.pro.abs,acp.i,col.org,acp.t,is.d,is.oid,cpro.rtpc,prod.d,stp.oid,rtp.i,rdm.oid,rtp.d,col.dept,ff.d,ff.c,col.pc,pub.t,kf.d,dis.t,col.oid,pro.t,per.sn,org.orcidId,per.on,ff.dept,rdm.t,org.n,dis.d,prod.oid,so.cn,dis.i,pro.a,pub.orcidId,pol.gt,rdm.i,rdm.d,so.oid,per.fnsn,per.org.n,per.pro.t,pro.orcidId,pub.a,col.d,per.orcidId,col.c,ip.i,pro.gr,pol.i,so.t,per.fn,col.i,ip.t,ff.oid,stp.i,so.i,cpro.rcpgm,cpro.hlt,col.pic,so.d,ff.t,ip.d,dis.oid,ip.oid,stp.d,rtp.oid,ff.org,kf.oid,stp.t&type=&selectedSortableField=score&selectedSortOrder=DESC"
  )
  curl::curl_download(url, destfile, quiet = quiet_download)
  
}
```

Testing this with your original search:

```r
dl_ukri('"climate change" OR "climate crisis"', destfile = "test.csv")
readr::read_csv("test.csv")
#> Rows: 5894 Columns: 25
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (23): FundingOrgName, ProjectReference, LeadROName, Department, ProjectC...
#> dbl  (2): AwardPounds, ExpenditurePounds
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
#> # A tibble: 5,894 × 25
#>    FundingOrgN…¹ Proje…² LeadR…³ Depar…⁴ Proje…⁵ PISur…⁶ PIFir…⁷ PIOth…⁸ PI OR…⁹
#>    <chr>         <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#>  1 ESRC          ES/W00… Univer… School… Fellow… Thew    Harriet Christ… http:/…
#>  2 AHRC          AH/W00… Univer… Arts L… Resear… Scott   Peter   Manley  <NA>   
#>  3 AHRC          2609218 Queen … Drama   Studen… <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
#>  4 UKRI          MR/V02… Univer… Politi… Fellow… Spaiser Viktor… <NA>    http:/…
#>  5 MRC           MC_PC_… Univer… <NA>    Intram… Alessi  Dario   Renato  <NA>   
#>  6 AHRC          1948811 Royal … School… Studen… <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
#>  7 EPSRC         2688399 Brunel… Chemic… Studen… <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
#>  8 ESRC          ES/T01… Univer… Social… Resear… Walker  Cather… Louise  http:/…
#>  9 AHRC          AH/X00… Queen … Drama   Resear… Herita… Paul    <NA>    http:/…
#> 10 ESRC          2272756 Univer… Sch of… Studen… <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>   
#> # … with 5,884 more rows, 16 more variables: StudentSurname <chr>,
#> #   StudentFirstName <chr>, StudentOtherNames <chr>, `Student ORCID iD` <chr>,
#> #   Title <chr>, StartDate <chr>, EndDate <chr>, AwardPounds <dbl>,
#> #   ExpenditurePounds <dbl>, Region <chr>, Status <chr>, GTRProjectUrl <chr>,
#> #   ProjectId <chr>, FundingOrgId <chr>, LeadROId <chr>, PIId <chr>, and
#> #   abbreviated variable names ¹​FundingOrgName, ²​ProjectReference, ³​LeadROName,
#> #   ⁴​Department, ⁵​ProjectCategory, ⁶​PISurname, ⁷​PIFirstName, ⁸​PIOtherNames, …
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Voilà. I also played around with the `fetchSize=25` which is in the original URL. But it does not seem to do anything, so I just omitted it.